# How to read data from excel > search from web > get datatable > write whole table into Excel in UIPath

Tags: rpa, uipath

Would like to check that how can I do the step as title? What I can do is only get text from web and write in Excel, I was trying to use Web Scraping but only 1 product will show in my excel sheet, is anyone know how to do it or is there any example? Please assist. Thanks.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HxtyuAiPTk

this is the video i followed and able to do that, but I hope that i can get datatable instead of get text only.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** You are likely using `Write Range` when you should be using `Append Range`. **/tl;dr**

My guess is that you are choosing the wrong Excel activity.

Note that Excel provides both a `Write Range` and an [`append range`](https://youtu.be/hFf3UQtJyGQ) activity. You are likely using `Write Range` rather than `Append Range`. In the image below I have highlighted in green the one you want and in red the one you are likely using.

[image]

### Append vs write

When you combine the [UiPath web scraping](https://youtu.be/x_713hTRsic) with the `append range`, you will get an aggregation of data. You are likely overwriting the same cell each time.

[image]

This image comes from the following YouTube video on [UiPath Web Scraping](https://youtu.be/NPpEUSp1AwY) and saving to Excel. It's similar to the video you linked to but uses append rather than write.

Comment: Hi Cameron McKenzie, thanks for your answer. I believe you are correct as i'm using wrong function. Anyway, i'm still unable to get what I want, do you mind to take a look my activity as I have uploaded to dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/rkbysdvti8mcfvl/Main.xaml?dl=0

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure why I will only get the 1st product i search in website and move to Excel, the second product i search won't able to save in Excel but the 1st product will save again, so there are 2 duplicate product in my Excel

Comment: Could it possibly be your selector? Perhaps you are always reading the same data. Make sure the title property of your selector is removed. That's the only other thing I can think of?

Comment: Hi Cameron McKenzie, I get what I want using append range. Another question is how can i add new column and insert data into existing column?

Comment: Oh, I have a great answer for that! Could you ask that as a new post on StackOverflow? There's not enough room to answer that as a comment. Keep the questions coming!